# annotate buttons onto uiimageview (like mkmapview without MapKit)

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uibutton, zooming

I have a UIImageView set on top of a scrollView. The image is a map, and I need to annotate buttons across the map to corresponding locations (very specific to the region). The buttons are visible, and they pan and scale accordingly when scrolled/zoomed, this works great. The issue is when the buttons are rendered on different screen sizes, the buttons are placed in different spots since auto-layout puts them the same distance from the edge of the screen, but the image has a different bounds property and is bigger/smaller depending on the device.

I've considered creating an MKMapView with a custom overlay of this image, but I was hoping to keep it super light-weight and avoid MapKit all together.

Any suggestions? Clarifications are fully encouraged :)

Comment: Do you add those buttons over map image view?

Comment: I'm adding these buttons as subviews on my scroll view, above the imageview

Answer (score 0):

You should add buttons as subviews on imageview so that buttons transform in the same way as imageview does.